# What is the preferred order of practicing Bach Sonatas and Partitas for solo violin?

Tags: practice, violin, classical-music, j-s-bach

As a violinist, it's always been hard for me to come up with an order of practicing Bach Sonatas and Partitas (BWV 1001-1006).

I also know that it's not all about *playing*, and *expression* is the key to playing (especially) Bach pieces.

So please:

1. Guide me through each of these 6 Sonatas and Partitas **by their parts** and tell me their challenges individually (regarding expressions and techniques, ideally by separation of bow and fingering).
2. Present a practice (or possibly performance) order by which I can make my way.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the preferred order of practicing Bach Sonatas and Partitas
>   for solo violin?

There was a [similar thread](https://www.violinist.com/discussion/archive/4806/) many years ago on Violinist.com.

This response was the most helpful and comes closest to answering the relative difficulty part of your question:

> The Royal Conservatory of Music Violin Syllabus (1999 edition) lists
>   the solo Bach pieces by grade, as follows:
>
> **Grade 8:**
>
> Partita number 2 in d minor--Giga
>
> Partita number 3 in E major--bouree or Minuets I and II or Gigue
>
> **Grade 9:**
>
> Partita number 1 in b minor--courante
>
> Partita number 2 in d minor--Allemande or Corrente or Sarabanda
>
> Partita number 3 in E major--Gavotte and Rondeau
>
> Sonata number 1 in g minor--adagio
>
> Sonata number 3 in C major--Allegro assai
>
> **Grade 10:**
>
> Partita number 1 in b minor--Allemande and Double or Sarabande and
>   Double or Tempo di bourree and Double
>
> Partita number 3 in E major--Preludio or Loure
>
> Sonata number 1 in g minor--Siciliana or Presto
>
> Sonata number 2 in a minor--Andante or Allegro
>
> Sonata number 3 in C major--Adagio or Largo
>
> **Performer's ARCT:**
>
> Partita number 2 in d minor--Chaconne
>
> Sonata number 1 in g minor--Fugue
>
> Sonata number 2 in a minor--Fugue
>
> Sonata number 3 in C major--Fugue

Comment: I want to know challenges regarding to each part too.
I was also aware of this thread on that site, but thanks anyways

Comment: Nathan Cole, First Associate Concertmaster of the LA Phil, has been working through some of these works on his YouTube channel (https://www.youtube.com/user/natesviolin/videos) and Facebook page under the generic title "Bach on the Road" on Mondays, Wednesdays, Fridays at 2pm Pacific. As part of what he does he goes through some of the challenges these pieces present and how to tackle them. Next one (C Major fugue) starts in 5 minutes as a livestream.